# Integration in MATLAB: Complicated integrand

Tags: matlab, integration

Can I solve the integral given below using Matlab?

$$\frac{C(J)}{C_0} =
\frac{2e^J}{\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{\frac{\gamma}{2}\left[1 - \sqrt{\rho}\cos(\theta/2)\right]}}{a_1^2 + a_2^2} [a_1\cos(ZJ-w) + a_2\sin(ZJ - w)]\, dZ$$
where
\begin{align}
&\theta = \arctan(v/u)\\
&u = 1 + \frac{4}{\gamma}\left[1 + \frac{ba + a(1 + Z^2)}{(1 + b)^2 + Z^2}\right]\\
&v = \frac{4Z}{\gamma}\left[1 + \frac{ab}{(1 + b)^2 + Z^2}\right]\\
&\rho = \sqrt{u^2 + v^2}\\
&b = \frac{af}{1 - f}\\
&a_1 = 1 + \sqrt{\rho}\cos(\theta/2) - Z\sqrt{\rho}\sin(\theta/2)\\
&a_2 = Z\left[1 + \sqrt{\rho}\cos(\theta/2)\right] + \sqrt{\rho}\sin(\theta/2)\\
&w = \frac{\gamma}{2}\sqrt{\rho}\sin(\theta/2)
\end{align}

Relation between $Z$ and $J$ is as follows:
$$Z = \frac{af}{1 - f} (J-y) \enspace .$$
$y$ varies in $[0, 1]$; $C_0=1$; $a= 0.065$; $f=0.7$.
I am new to Matlab. Any help will be highly appreciated. I ran the following code (gamma is not y and gamma=m=60, J=1/0.7, O=theta, C=C(J)/C0), but matlab is busy from last 12-13 hours!!

```
syms z
m=60;
a = 0.065;
f = 0.7;
b = a*f/(1-f);
u = 1+((4/m)*(1+(b*a+a*(1+z.^2))/((1+b).^2)+z.^2));
v = (4*z/m)*(1+(a*b/(1+b).^2+z.^2));
p = sqrt(u.^2+v.^2);
O = atan(v/u);
a1 = 1+sqrt(p)*cos(O/2)-z*sqrt(p)*sin(O/2);
a2 = z*(1+sqrt(p)*cos(O/2))+sqrt(p)*sin(O/2);
w = (m/2)*sqrt(p)*sin(O/2);
fun = (exp(m/2*(1-sqrt(p)*cos(O/2)))/(a1.^2+a2.^2))*(a1*cos((z/0.7)-w)+a2*sin((z/0.7)-w));
I = int(fun, z, 0, inf);
C = 2*exp(1/0.7)*I/pi;
display(C)
plot(z,C)
xlabel('Z')
ylabel('concentration')
if C>1
    stop
end
```

Comment: Have you tried the [`integral`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) function, or one of the other integration functions in matlab, and did it work? If it didn't work, can you say how it failed?

Comment: @nicoguaro, sorry I forgot to mention y is not γ. γ=60.  I tried to run the code mentioned in answer with J=1/0.7, but matlab is busy from last 12 hours!!

Comment: Do you want to integrate that equation analytically? MATLAB is not the best tool for that aim.

Comment: @nicoguaro I want to solve it numerically! should I change the upper limit of integral to some finite number?

Comment: @user16362, the first thing you are doing in your code is telling Matlab that your variable `z` is a symbolic variable. Then, it is trying to make the computation using the Symbolic Algebra Package is has.

Comment: If you want to solve this numerically, then you probably should be using symbolic math and the `int` function. Try `integral` as suggested by @Kiril: `integral(matlabFunction(simplify(fun)),0,Inf)`. Although with an oscillatory integrand, you may want to try alternative quadrature schemes to check your answer (the exponential term may provide sufficient damping at large values however). See [this question](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/5093/4474)